# How to change with selection to whole worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How could I change this code so I don't have to first select all the cells? I would like this to work without selecting the cells first, instead, it should work with the `worksheet("Phase")`.

```
Option Explicit 
 
Sub RemoveFormats() 
     'Remove all formatting except changes in font and font size
     
     'Turn off screen updates to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
     
    With Selection 
         'Remove cell colors
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 
         
         'Remove all cell borders
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone 
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone 
         
         'Remove all special font properties and formatting
        With .Font 
            .FontStyle = "Regular" 
            .Strikethrough = False 
            .Superscript = False 
            .Subscript = False 
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone 
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 
        End With 
    End With 
     
     'Restore screen updates to display changes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about applying your macro to the entire sheet called "Phase", you would simply reference the `Worksheet.Cells` instead of the `Selection` object property to get all cells of a worksheet.

```
Sub YourMethod()
    '// code...
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Phase").Cells
        'Remove cell colors
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 
    '// more code....
    End With

end Sub
```